# Receive generic class type

Tags: java, android, generics, gson

I wish to create generic function that will receive class and then return it with the Gson data.
This is example of the code I need to impliment, can you please help me with this?

```
ClassType? dealWithClass (String st, Class cls)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(st,cls.class);
}

MyClass1 mc1 = dealWithClass("some gson string",MyClass1.class)
MyClass2 mc2 = dealWithClass("some second gson string",MyClass2.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple use of generics:

```
public <T>  T dealWithClass (String st, Class<T> cls)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(st,cls);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

> Just like type declarations, **method declarations can be generic**—that is, **parameterized by one or more type parameters**.

```
<T> T dealWithClass(String st, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(st, clazz);
}
```

Comment: you forgot the `st` parameter